# Apply css rules to selector using jquery with media queries

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a website which displays a number plate, the plate contains an image and a border which sit next to each other. The user has an option to turn the image on or off, if it's turned off the border fills the entire plate. If the image is turned on, the border width will adjust accordingly.  I've got this working fine, however, for different breakpoints the border needs to adjust slightly and I need to implement this using jQuery.

To make the above work without media queries I am using the following code the (#gb-prefix is the image and #plateBorder is the border):

```
jQuery(document.body).on('change','#gb-prefix',function(){
    if(jQuery('#gb-prefix').val() == 'Yes')
    {
        jQuery("#plateBorder").css({"width": "91%", "left": "60px"});
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#plateBorder").css({"width": "98%", "left": "7px"});
    }
});
```

This works fine for anything above 1200px.

I'm working with bootstrap breakpoints so I'll need to work with those dimensions.

Can someone shed some light on how to use

```
jQuery(window).resize(function()
```

with what I'm already using?

Comment: I'm not clear why you need to do this in jQuery? It would make more sense to amend the border in the CSS media query.

Comment: The #gb-prefix is selectable using a select field on the front end. So I need the border to react when a selection is made. Here's the page, so you can see what I'm talking about: http://www.fullhousecustoms.com/product/520-x-110mm-uk-standard-number-plate/

Comment: So add/remove a class based on the value of that `select`, then amend the styling of that class in the media query.